# Symmetric Groups and Commutativity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

I just finished my homework which involved, among many things, the following question:

**Let $S_{3}$ be the symmetric group $\{1,2,3\}$. Determine the number of elements that commute with (23)**.

Now, solving this was unproblematic - for those interested; the answer is 2. However, it got me thinking whether or not there is a general solution to this type of question.Thus, my question is:

**Let $S_{n}$ be the symmetric group $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Determine the number of elements in $S_{n}$ that commute with $(ij)$ where $1\leq i,j \leq n $.**

Comment: Is the notation $(23)$ equivalent to the permutation $(1 3 2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use orbit stabilizer theorem. The conjugacy class of $(i j)$ has size $ n \choose 2$. Therefore, $n!/{n \choose 2}$ elements of $S_n$ commute with $(i j)$.

Comment: Very nice way to do it. Note that another way to write the number is $2\cdot(n-2)!$ (it commutes with precisely those permutations that fix $i$ and $j$ plus those that switch $i$ and $j$).

Comment: Serkan and TobiasKildeoft thank you both for your contributions. Would it be right of me to presume that the conjugacy class of (ijk) would be of size $\begin{pmatrix} n \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 1):

- Let $\pi, \phi\in S_{\Omega}$. Then $\pi, \phi$ are disjoint if $\pi$ moves $\omega\in \Omega$ then $\phi$ doesn't move $\omega$.

For example, $(2,3)$ and $(4,5)$ in $S_6$ are disjoint. indeed, $\{2,3\}\cap\{4,5\}=\emptyset$.

Theorem: If $\pi, \phi\in S_{\Omega}$ are disjoint then $\pi\phi=\phi\pi$.

Comment: But what about those elements that commute with it without being disjoint from it?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I pointed that when the intersection of alphabets in $\pi$ and $\{i,j\}$ is $\emptyset$ then $\pi$ could commute with $(i,j)$. :)

Comment: @BabakS.:⇯ ╋ (◕‿◕)